# Load jQuery only once on many-framed page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

A key screen in my application involves a HTML page with several `iframe`s performing various functions. All of these will need access to jQuery. In the interest of speeding up loading time, and reducing HTTP traffic (though I know caching could help with this), it would be good if the jQuery code itself were loaded only once. If my page is like so

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="jquery-1.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
      <body>
         <iframe src="other.html"></iframe>
         <div id="foo"> ... stuff here ... </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Then inside `other` I can refer to `parent.$('#foo')` but that will refer to the parent's "foo" element, not the child's. Is there a way to use the parent's "instance" of jQuery on the child document or elements in it?

Comment: Have you tried `$ = parent['jQuery']` in the `iframe`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var $ = window.parent.$;
$('#foo'); // parent's frame's #foo, is the same as "window.parent.$('#foo');"
```

and:

```
var $ = window.parent.$;
$('#foo', document); // this frame's #foo because the current document is given as context
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I addressed that in my question. `parent.$('#foo')` refers to the parent. I want to refer to the child.

Comment: No you are misunderstanding that. parent.$('foo') is the parent's dom. But I am saying you need to copy jquery to the inner iframe and the do $('foo'). Which should look for the inner dom. Please try it first.

Comment: I updated so you can see what I am talking about. $ is nothing more than jquery libs which work on the frame you are in.

Comment: ok I see. That makes sense. Sort of. I don't really understand how `parent.$(something)` could have a different behavior from `$=parent.$;$(something)` since it's just a variable assignment. But I'll give it a try

Comment: `$('#foo');` will refer to the parent frame dom by default because jQuery caches the reference to `document` only once (once, which is at the time it was downloaded in the parent frame), not from the current scope each time. If you need to make a lot of queries to the child DOM using the parent's jQuery, you can cache the result of `$(document)` like `var $child = $(document);` and then use it like `$child.find(..);` `$child.append( ... );` etc.

Comment: @Krinkle Your change is not right. `$` is just a jQuery object which looks for `document`. What you changed it to is actually not true and wrong. I'll need to revert it. If you can provide me with a working example then I won't change it. Also `$(document).find()` is deprecated in favor to `$(..., document)`

Comment: I also don't see it being cached. `getElementById` is called on document. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L143

Comment: @Amir Raminfar: `$(someDocument).find()` is NOT deprecated in favor to `$(..., someDocument)`. Neither is deprecated and using .find() is the more readable and faster. the context 2nd argument is last in the jQuery initializer and does `return $(context).find(selector)`.

Comment: @Amir Raminfar: And yes, it is cached. Just because it uses a variable called `document` doesn't mean it is an implied global. When `jquery.js` is downloaded and executed, one of the first lines is `var document = window.document` ([jquery.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/intro.js#L19)). But wether it is cached or not doesn't matter, in the scope where jQuery is defined, it will always be looking for the global scope of the window it was defined in, not in the global scope of the window it is called from.

Comment: @Krinkle I tried it out and yes you were right. It does cache it. I will use part of your answer. But I still prefer `$(..., someDocument)`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure each IFRAME references the exact same version of jquery. It should only get loaded once and be cached by the browser. IFRAMES don't have access to scripts of their parents.

You might also want to consider using a CDN for Jquery (such as [Google's CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html)) to improve performance.

Comment: I'll do some experiments on this. That wasn't the behavior I thought I saw, but it's possible I had forcibly disabled caching in my browser.

Comment: I wonder if it doesn't cache it because all iframe's send the request for the javascript at the same time. Curious too here.

Answer (score 0):

We solved it with:

```
var window.jQuery = window.$ = function( selector, context ) {
    return window.parent.jQuery(selector, context?context:window.document)
}
```